# Identify sending user, Python IRC

Tags: python, bots, irc, twitch

So I made a Twitch.tv bot for my own channel, after having fun with it a little bit, I wanted to have some command restricted to some users, and some commands that can say the users name, for example:

```
Username reply example:

Person1: !tea
PythonBot: Would you like some tea, Person1?

Admin restriction example:

Person1: !ban Person2
PythonBot: I'm sorry, Person1, This command is restricted to admins only.
```

Ok, So here is the code I'm using (I will be modifying it soon to make it my own)

```
import socket
import threading



bot_owner = '~Not Today~'
nick = '~Not Today~'
channel = '~Not Today~'
server = 'irc.twitch.tv'
password = '~Not Today~'

queue = 13

irc = socket.socket()
irc.connect((server, 6667))

irc.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER ' + nick + ' 0 * :' + bot_owner + '\r\n')
irc.send('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')

def message(msg):
    global queue
    queue = 5
    if queue < 20:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG' + channel + ' :' + msg + '\r\n')
    else:
        print 'Message Deleted'

def queuetimer():
    global queue
    queue = 0
    threading.Timer(30,queuetimer).start()
queuetimer()

while True:
    botdata = irc.recv(1204)
    botuser = botdata.split(':')[1]
    botuser = botuser.split('!')[0]
    print botdata

    if botdata.find('PING') != -1:
        irc.send(botdata.replace('PING', 'PONG'))
    if botdata.find('!res') != -1:
        irc.send(botdata.replace('!res', '1600x900'))
```

Comment: Have you seen the Python IRC bots SuPyBot / Gribble / Limnoria ?

Comment: Is your code working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twitch IRC raw message is like

> :jkm!jkm@jkm.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #trumpsc :needs Kappa

for above msg, it actually means user`jkm` at channel `trumpsc` saying `needs Kappa`

for your code, the method to get `botuser` is right, but you don't have the message the user sent, add following code should get the message

```
botmsg = botdata.split(':')[2]
```

so you get the message and username, the next step would be handling them.
Here would be some example for your need. For me, I will prepared a `adminuserList` and `commmandList` for other command, but I will simplify it here.

```
def commmanHandler(botuser, botmsg):         # botmsg = '!ban user1'  
    command = botmsg.split(' ')[0]           # command = '!ban'
    command = command[1:]                    # command = 'ban'
    argu = message.split(' ')[1]             # argu = 'user1' 

    if command not in commmandList:         
        raise Exception("command not support")

    if command == 'ban':                     # ban command, or using switch
        # check if admin
        if botuser not in adminList:
            raise Exception("I'm sorry, " + botuser + ", This command is restricted to admins only.")
        # admin, able to ban
        irc.send('PRIVMSG' + channel + ' :' + '.ban ' + argu)
```

then call this function in your while loop to handle all message you get

```
try:
    commmanHandler(botuser, botmsg)
except Exception, e:
    print e
    irc.send('PRIVMSG' + channel + ' :' + e)
```

here would be my solution, and also, don't forget to give the bot **moderator** privilege.